# Null activity in Fragment even when setting in onAttach()

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, fragment

I have code that looks like this:

(Note:  Notice the line at the bottom where I get reports of a NullPointerException.  Also, this has been heavily edited for this posting but I believe all of the relevant code is included)

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

     public SettingsActivity activity;

     @Override
     public void onAttach(Context context) {
         super.onAttach(context);

         if (context instanceof Activity) {
             activity = (SettingsActivity) context;
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

         addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

         final SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
     }


     @Override
     public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String prefKey) {

         // The line below gets many NullPointerException reports
         SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
     }
 }
```

I thought by setting the `activity` variable in `onAttach()` would almost assure that is is not null.  (instead of using `getActivity()`)

The instances I have of `getActivity()` have 0 reports of ever being null.  It seems I just need to use that instead.  **But I would like to know how activity is null and is changing it to `getActivity()` the way to go?**

FWIW, I am not using a `onDetach()` in this class.

Just a guess:  It seems to me that `onAttach()` can be called well before `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` might be called, so maybe the `activity` becomes null by then?

There is always the possibility the `activity` variable is not `null` and it is something else in that line, but this seems to be the most obvious to me?

Comment: Why do you need to create a SharedPreferences object at all when it's passed as a parameter?

Comment: @Submersed Assuming those objects contain the same data, I guess It was an oversight.  I'd still like to know what's up with the null `activity` situation though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
@Override
public void onAttach (Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity)
}
```

instead

```
@Override
public void onAttach (Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
}
```

Althought the first function was deprecated but it still work as well. Let try.

Comment: Not sure I like going back to deprecated stuff for fixes (unless the new stuff has known bugs which is really not the case here)